# How to save a removed string in a new string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have this function :

```
string = string.replace(/^.*?([a-zA-Z])/, '$1');
```

and I'd like to save both strings : the one after the expression and the one removed.

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking... it sounds like you just want to keep the original value of `string` stored somewhere as well as the replaced version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javacript">
var str = '44234lol';
var parts = str.split(/([a-zA-Z]+)/);
alert(parts[0]);
alert(parts[1]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This would show what was removed from the original string and what you're left with (I've altered your regex but you could use the same technique)  -

```
var portionremoved;
var string = '1234GF'

string = string.replace(/(\d+)([A-Z]+)/,function (removed,first,second) {
    portionremoved = first;
    return second;
});

alert(portionremoved);
alert(string);
```

Comment: The John Kurlak solution looks more easy, isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

```
string1 = string.replace(/^.*?([a-zA-Z])/, '$1');
```

Note that string.replace returns the replaced string while *string* still holds the previous value.

Comment: Don't be so rough on them :p  The original question wasn't easy to understand.